# How to fix a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source?

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, primefaces

We have an application which uses JSF2 Primefaces and Spring. The application works fine. But this happens when i add a chart into an xhtml file:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">

            <p:chart type="pie" model="#{Statistique.pieChart}" title="Tache Critique et Non Critique"style="width:400px;height:300px"  />

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

this is the stack trace:

```
juin 03, 2014 7:58:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/HCP] threw exception [null source] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:67)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:69)
    at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:69)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:256)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:245)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and this is the `Statistique` Component:

```
@Scope("session")
@Component("Stats")
public class StatsImpl implements Statistique  {
    @Autowired
    private TacheService tacheService;
    private PieChartModel pieChart;
    private List<Tache> listTaches;
    public StatsImpl (){


    construct,getter and seters ...
    @Transactional
    public PieChartModel getStats()
    {
        listTaches=(List<Tache>) tacheService.loadTaches();
        int critique=0;
        int nomCritique=0;
        for(int i=0;i<listTaches.size();i++)

        {

            if(listTaches.get(i).getType().equals("Critique"))critique++;
            else nomCritique++;
        }
        pieChart.set("Tache Critique", critique);
        pieChart.set("Tache Non Critique", nomCritique);
        return pieChart;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well A few things I have noticed:
1. Jsf Bean convention need to be called with small letter of the class name `Statistique.pieChart` Should be `statistique.pieChart`

1. If this is the bean you are using you should call him `statsImpl.pieChart`
2. Jsf 2 support Dependency injection so you might want to use instead of spring beans. Just for you to consider to keep order of things.

I suggest that you will look at this tutorial if Spring + Jsf + Hibernate simple project. Make sure you are doing the same.

Hope that helps

EDIT:

As much as i know you can't call spring bean with jsf page. You need to use jsf bean but i am not sure, Anyway i would suggest to use jsf in order to avoid annoying issues. It just need to save your time.